# How to get the project path in command line

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, testng

I create a TestNG project in Eclipse, and I use `System.getProperty("user.dir")` to get the base folder (like "D:\project\selenium") of the project, but when I run the TestNG in the command line, the base folder returns "C:\users\username\", is there any way to solve this question?

Comment: Does System.getProperty("user.dir") return expected result when the code is running not in console but inside Eclipse?

Comment: Yes, it returns the expected result when running in Eclipse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A similar issue was fixed in the latest version of the eclipse plugin: https://github.com/cbeust/testng/issues/903

You should try to upgrade the plugin.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the issue is that when you run it via command line, your `user.dir` corresponds to your global user directory (C:\users\username).

Before you run your tests, try to change your current directory to the one where your Eclipse project is hosted (i.e. `cd D:\project\selenium`). And after that run your tests.

Unfortunately I do not have Windows at hand right now, so can't test it by myself.