# Unable to download a file when chromedriver is in headless mode. How to get it work?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, headless, headless-browser

During the test, a file (.html) will be downloaded from the web application & I have to verify that file by opening it on the browser. In the non-headless mode, my test is working fine. But whenever I'm going to headless mode, that file is not getting downloaded to the download path (i.e. pointed in the "user.dir").  My chrome driver version is 2.44.609538 & selenium version is 3.14.

Comment: Please explain your problem in detail. Is your file downloaded at wrong path? Are you getting some error? Please share the code which you have tried already. You should add [mcve] in question.

Comment: When running in the non-headless mode, the file is downloaded in the user directory. The test is running perfectly. The problem begins when I'm running the test in headless mode.

Comment: "User.dir" changes in headless mode. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51168671/screenshot-with-katalon-and-chrome-headless-mode.

Comment: My implementation was working well but after I updated the Capybara gem to 3.33.0 and the Selenium gem to 4.0.0.alpha6 I am facing the same problem.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently this could help you

Shawn Button post the answer related with it.

[Downloading with chrome headless and selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45631715/downloading-with-chrome-headless-and-selenium?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

Are you running the test from the command line?

Because, according to an answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34080696/how-to-get-the-project-path-in-command-line) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51168671/screenshot-with-katalon-and-chrome-headless-mode), when you run it via command line, your `user.dir` corresponds to your global user directory (C:\users\username).

Answer (score 0):

This worked for our ruby implementation:

```
Capybara.register_driver :scrapping_driver do |app|
      options = Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome::Options.new
      options.add_argument('--headless')
      options.add_argument('--disable-popup-blocking')
      options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
      options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
      options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
      options.add_argument('--window-size=1366,2000')
      options.add_preference(:download, directory_upgrade: true,
                                prompt_for_download: false,
                                default_directory: "#{Rails.root}/")
      options.add_preference(:browser, set_download_behavior: { behavior: 'allow' })
      Selenium::WebDriver::Service.driver_path = Webdrivers::Chromedriver.driver_path
      driver = Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, browser: :chrome, options: options)
    end
```

Pay attention at download behaviour

Answer (score 0):

I met same situation.

Headless mode is very faster. So your code might be implemented to detect download(DL).

### Solution.

1. (Current your process?) .click for DL -> Detecting download file generation.
2. (My solution) Detecting download file generation -> .click for DL.

I implemented the above mechanism using callback function.